# Magento - opening order with pending payment status magento crashes

Tags: magento

i reall ydont know what to do, when admin tries to view an order with pending payment status the whole magento crashes and produces this. What to do?

```
Warning: include(Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Cc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

#0 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage/Pa...', '/var/www/client...', 93, Array)
#1 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Payment_Bl...')
#3 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Payment/Info.php(32): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Payment_Bl...')
#4 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): include('/var/www/client...')
#5 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Paypal_Blo...')
#6 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php(125): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Paypal_Blo...')
#7 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(50): Mage_Payment_Helper_Data->getInfoBlock(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#8 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php(44): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->setPayment(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#9 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Payment->_beforeToHtml()
#10 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_payment', true)
#12 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Info.php(112): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_payment')
#13 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info->getPaymentHtml()
#14 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/client...')
#15 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info))
#21 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/client...')
#22 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#23 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#30 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#31 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/client...')
#32 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#33 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#38 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(119): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#39 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
#40 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#41 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#42 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#43 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#44 /var/www/clients/client22/web187/web/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#45 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Cc.php

this page is not there in Projectfolder/app/code/core/

add the file/class in Projectfolder/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Cc.php

it will work..

Comment: Thanks, it works now :) Dont know what happened, the file was missing on server..